# Repeated edit summary in timeline view

Tags: bug, status-completed, timeline, edit-summary

Have a look at the [timeline view](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/478075/timeline) of the edits on this question: [Creating files in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/478075/313758)

[image: screenshot of repeated text]

The edit summary of my revision 12 hours ago has been repeated multiple times in the timeline view. This is not shown in more conventional views, such as the [revision history view](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/478075/revisions). I can also testify that I didn't repeat that revision summary multiple times when I was actually typing it in.

<del>I couldn't find any other timelines that show this problem, so this might just be an isolated case.</del>

This is also happening in the occasional [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1913/could-the-process-of-ageing-be-slowed-to-extend-the-human-lifespan) elsewhere ([revision history](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/1913/revisions)/[timeline](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/1913/timeline))

Comment: My original thought is that it may have had to do with multiple revisions in one grace period, but I checked some of my revisions and none of them show anything more than one instance of the latest edit summary. So an unusual case, this... I wonder what caused it here.

Comment: Do you happen to remember if you did multiple edits within the grace period?  As in, additional two edits showing the two repetitions?  I'm seeing the same [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/38025/revisions) ([timeline](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/38025/timeline)) but could have sworn I did this in one edit and no more within the grace period.

Comment: Noticed a fourfold timeline repetition similar to the above on Bio and edited it in :)

Comment: The issue is that you changed `n` many separate things. If you edit the title, body, and tags all in one go, the message is repeated three times, and so on. I guess it's doing some sort of collapsing for the default case (i.e. edited title; n characters edited in body; edited tags) without realising that all three are using the same (custom) reason.

Comment: "What I tell you three times is true." -- The system is just agreeing that you made a good edit.?. (^_^)

Comment: Ha, the irony, it's happening on this question too - see the "grammar" edit :L Think @Tim has got it though

Answer (score 3):

We are recording the details of retags, title edits and body edits as separate historical events. So revisions that have more than one of these has several historical records with the same comment (that includes all the changes...).

I have added a distinct clause to ensure duplicate comments no longer appear.

With you in the next build.